# Kettle - Duplicate key error using Insert/Update

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, kettle

I have a postgres database which I ETL with Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle).

Data loading was configured using the Insert/Update box with the following configuration.

[image: Insert/Update Configuration]

However, I'm getting this error message from the database.

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error inserting/updating row
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_cardid_cards"
Detail: Key (cardid)=(91c2eb15-75f4-4081-8b51-aebcc2fc0116) already exists.
```

I've read in another question that the duplicate key must be composed in order to kettle insert/update's box correct working.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a <= in your unique key lookup, which allows to get more than one cardid+updatedate and this is inconsistent.

use **UNIQUE** keys always for insert/update. In fact you are using this constrain already but only in the postgres side, you have to follow the same constrain from pdi side. Have a look in the table DDL to see the uniqueness constrain declaration

probably it can do the trick using = instead of <= on the second column of your lookup.

Comment: I was under the impression that Insert/Update step was likely an upsert but it fails in this case.
The uniqueness should be on the id of the table, my idea was to update the record if a date was higher than the record present on the table.

As you mention, I have to follow the same key that is present on the table.